# Alternative to deprecated sqlite pragma "default_cache_size"

Tags: python, sqlite

The sqlite docs says that using the `pragma default_cache_size` is deprecated. I looked, but I couldn't see any explanation for why. Is there a reason for this? I'm working on an embedded python program, and we open and close connections a lot. Is the only alternative to use the `pragma cache_size` on every database connection?

Comment: I always wondered about that too. I suspect it might be because the cache size is only related to the hosting process and not the database (or consistency of the data). `cache_size` *is* the alternative AFAIK. SQLite could always be recompiled with a different default ;-)

Comment: @pst: That's what I did. I recompiled sqlite with different cache size and page size values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Firefox is massively using SQLite I wouldn't be surprised if this request came from their camp to prevent any kind of 3rd party interference (e.g. "trashing" with large/small/invalid/obscure values) by this kind of pragma propagating through all database connections

Hence, my strong belief is that there is no alternative and that you really need to set `cache_size` for each database connection

Comment: That's a good point about 3rd parties messing with your database. Didn't think about that. Recompiling with a different default (as well as a few other changes) was the better solution anyway. I'll select your answer since there's probably not much more to say.